# cannot open any file by intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent, installation, package

I'm new to android and want to open files (any format) in my application. If the file is `apk` try to install the file, if the file is video or audio try to play the file.
here is my creation intent:

```
public class DownloadFilesAction {

public void openFile(Context applicationContext, String fileName) {
    File file = this.getFileByFileNameInDownloadsFolder(fileName);
    if (file == null)
        return;
    Intent intent = createIntentToOpenFile(applicationContext, file);
    PackageManager packageManager = applicationContext.getPackageManager();
    if (packageManager != null) {
        try {
            if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                startActivity(applicationContext, intent);
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException exception) {
            Sentry.captureException(exception);
        }
    }
}

private Intent createIntentToOpenFile(Context applicationContext, File file) {
    Uri fileUri = getFilePathUri(applicationContext, file);
    try {
        String mime = applicationContext.getContentResolver().getType(fileUri);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, mime);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        return intent;
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        Sentry.captureException(exception);
    }
    return null;
}

private Uri getFilePathUri(Context context, File file) {
    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "package_name", file);
}
}
```

this is my manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
    tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

this code now find the target file but does not open the file.

what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Who put that file in Download folder?

Comment: `this code now find the target file` What do you mean?